# Splitting Fields and Non-constant Polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I had a question I was stuck on:

Let $p(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$. Prove that there exists a splitting field $E$ for $p(x)$ such that $[E : F] \leq  n!$.

My start:

By a theorem, we know that there exist a splitting field $E$ for $p(x)$ since $p(x) \in F[X]$.

$p(x)$ has degree $n$, and since $E$ of $F$ is a splitting field for $p(x)$, there are elements $\alpha_1 ..., \alpha_n$ in $E$ such that $E = F(\alpha_1 ..., \alpha_n)$ and also $p(x) = (x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2)...(x - \alpha_n)$

I have no idea where to go from here, I feel as I'm really close. Any hints would be extremely helpful for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use induction on the degree of the polynomial and multiplicativity of the dimensions in towers of fields.

Comment: Is induction the only way to attack the problem? Or is it the easiest way? :P I thought of using it, but I wanted to try a different approach.

Comment: There is an easier solution, if you are allowed to use some Galois theory, but it is not very elementary... Otherwise I think induction really is the most natural solution, because we understand splitting fields as 'built up' from the ground field by adjoining roots one at a time.

Comment: We haven't learned any sort of Galois theory, so I don't think it'll be a way to do it. Anyways, if that's the case... I think I'll just use induction! Thank you.

Comment: @walcher I really like the statement :  induction really is the most natural solution, because we understand splitting fields as 'built up' from the ground field by adjoining roots one at a time :-)